# Is Defecting from your country at war haram

Tags: war

if you defect in war to the enemy side is it haram? if so would it still be if  the side you are fighting for is bad/evil (nazis,commuists,etc). would it stil be haram?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam stackexchange. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] to get familair with our site. A Muslim shouldn't fight Muslimsanything else needs more details to be answered adequately.